# Binding classes non-statically in Guice

Tags: scala, guice

In my Scala project, I use Guice to bind a number of classes that occur in triples, something like:

```
bind[Foo1Component].to[Foo1]
bind[Foo2Component].to[Foo2]
bind[Foo3Component].to[Foo3]
// And so on for Bar, Baz, etc.
```

I thought it would be nice to have a function to which I pass the string `"Foo"` and have it do all three bindings.  The closest I've been able to get is:

```
def bindAll(name: String): Unit = {
  bind(Class.forName(name + "1Component")).to(Class.forName(name + "1"))
  // likewise for 2 and 3, or do it in a loop
}
```

...but this gives me a lengthy error message to the effect that the compiler can't figure out which overloaded `to` method I want.  Since `bind(classOf[Foo1Component]).to(classOf[Foo1])` works, I suppose the issue is that `Class.forName` returns a `Class[_]` rather than a `Class` with an appropriate type parameter.

Is there any way to bind classes dynamically like this?

Comment: I dont think this is possible, check  related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372936/guice-set-bindings-from-an-xml-file